# Equation with integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have the following equation:

$$\int (x-b)^n(x-c)^mdx = \frac{f(x)}{a}.$$

I want to compute value of $a$, but I don't know how can I escape this integral. $b$, $c$, $n$, $m$ are constants.

Comment: What about $f$?

Comment: I don't know specific representation of **f** function. It's possible to compute this at all?

Comment: Something about $f$ should be given, for example that it is a monic  polynomial. Otherwise, we can multiply both $f$ and $a$ by an arbitrary constant ($\neq 0$) and the value of $a$ cannot be determined.

Comment: I am sure that `f` is a real polynomial, but I'm not sure that `f` is monic polynomial.

Comment: Then its as simple as this: its not possible to compute what $a$ is. If you say $f$ is monic then its simple: $a = n+m+1$ (consider the largest power of $x$ on the l.h.s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could derivate both sides and then solve for a - If $f'$ is not too complicated then you at least escape the integral.

$a = \frac{f'(x)} {(x-b)^n(x-c)^m} $

Comment: So thanks for the answer.